# Access related table field value in django template

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to access a Django related field value in a Django template:

```
            {% for item in order %}
            <tr>
              
              <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
              <td class="text-left">{{ item.created }}</td>
              <td class="text-left">{{ item.payments__charge_status }}</td>
              <td class="text-left">{{ item.shipping_method_name }}</td>
              <td class="text-right">£{{ item.total_gross_amount }}</td>
              
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Actual queryset defined in views.py:

```
orders = Order.objects.values().filter(created__range=(start_date, end_date)).filter(Q(payments__charge_status="fully-charged") | Q(payments__charge_status="not-charged"))
```

Payment is in a different table and I can access using **`payments__charge_status`** in the view but not in the actual template.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Updated with models.py for Payment Model:

....

```
class Payment(models.Model):


    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, null=True, related_name="payments", on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
```

Comment: Show us your models

Comment: updated with the order model field we are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your database modeling order can have multiple payments ( [Many-to-One](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) )so payments is a QuerySet you should iterate through

```
{% for payment in item.payments.all %}
          {{ payment.charge_status }   
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can I access this using my existing queryset?

Comment: I would guess you should read a bit more about Django ORM for general knowledge about it. You can optimize retrieval of related data using
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Thank you, this worked but I had to remove .values() from the queryset